# PHP like/dislike button working only the first time

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to implement a like/dislike button on my page. I managed to get the button to work (it changes like to dislike and vice versa when clicked) and it also creates or deletes the like on the database table. The problem now is the counter of likes. It works only the first time i click the button, i.e. if initially there are `2 likes` and i dislike the post the post shows `1 likes`, but if I try to click again on it, it keeps showing `1 like` and I have to reload the page to see it change to `2 likes`.

This is what I have so far:

JQUERY

```
$(document).on('click', ".miPiace", function() {
    trova = '';
    commentoORisposta = '';
    valCOR = '';
    var comOrisp;       

    try{
        trova = $(this).parentsUntil("#fermamiQui");
        commentoORisposta = trova.find(".idCommento");
        comOrisp = 'commento';
        valCOR = commentoORisposta.val();

    } catch(err){
        trova = $(this).parentsUntil(".infoCommento");
        commentoORisposta = trova.find(".idRisposta");
        comOrisp = 'risposta';
        valCOR = commentoORisposta.val();

    }
    valCOR = commentoORisposta.val();



    if ($(this).hasClass('fa-thumbs-o-up')) {
        $(this).removeClass('fa-thumbs-o-up');
        $(this).addClass('fa-thumbs-up');

        $.get( "lib/ottieniCose.php", { like: "", id: valCOR, comOrisp: comOrisp } )
            .done(function( data ) {
            trova.find('.numDiLikes').replaceWith('<p>' + data + ' likes</p>');
        });


    }else if($(this).hasClass('fa-thumbs-up')){
        $(this).removeClass('fa-thumbs-up');
        $(this).addClass('fa-thumbs-o-up');

        $.get( "lib/ottieniCose.php", { remLike: "", id: valCOR, comOrisp: comOrisp } )
            .done(function( data ) {
            trova.find('.numDiLikes').replaceWith('<p>' + data + ' likes</p>');
        });


    };
});
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_GET['like'])) {

    if ($_GET['comOrisp'] == 'commento') {

        $commento->set_likes($_GET['id'], true);
        return print $commento->get_likes($_GET['id'], true);

    } elseif ($_GET['comOrisp'] == 'risposta') {

        $commento->set_likes($_GET['id'], false);
        return print $commento->get_likes($_GET['id'], false);
    }
} elseif (isset($_GET['remLike'])) {

    if ($_GET['comOrisp'] == 'commento') {

        $commento->remove_likes($_GET['id'], true);
        return print $commento->get_likes($_GET['id'], true);

    } elseif ($_GET['comOrisp'] == 'risposta') {

        $commento->remove_likes($_GET['id'], false);
        return print $commento->get_likes($_GET['id'], false);
    }
}
```

Other PHP file where there is the $commenti class

```
public function get_likes($id, $commento){

    $idComm = 0;
    $idRisp = 0;

    $retVal = ($commento) ? $idComm = $id : $idRisp = $id;

    if ($idComm != 0){
        $query = "SELECT commento, 
                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes 
                    WHERE commento = {$idComm}) 
                    AS like_count FROM likes";

    } elseif($idRisp != 0){
        $query = "SELECT risposta, 
                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes 
                    WHERE risposta = {$idRisp}) 
                    AS like_count FROM likes";

    }

    $trovaQuanti = mysqli_query($_SESSION['connessione'], $query);
    $trovaDavveroQuanti = mysqli_fetch_assoc($trovaQuanti);

    if ($trovaDavveroQuanti == null) {
        return '0';
    }

    return $trovaDavveroQuanti['like_count'];

}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try a normal `$.ajax` call. And turn off caching. Sometimes this causes an issue where you need to refresh to see the changes.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    url: "lib/ottieniCose.php",
    data: { like: "", id: valCOR, comOrisp: comOrisp },
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(html){
        trova.find('.numDiLikes').html('<p>' + data + ' likes</p>');
    }
});
```